# How do I use an 'if' statement in Perl?

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
if ($ARGV[0]=="-v") {
    print "MY name: abc\n";
    print "MY student ID:111110\n";
}
if ($ARGV[0]=="-s" && $ARGV[1]==printing_usage_file) {
    open (INFILE, $ARGV[1]) or die "An input file is required as argument\n";
    $totalbytes=0;
    $data="";
    while(<INFILE>) {
        chomp();
        @data=split(/,/);
        $totalbytes += $data[1];
    }
    print "Total number of bytes printed: $totalbytes\n";
}
```

In this case, what I want is when I run `./perl.pl -v`, it prints `my name` and `id`.

When I run `./perl.pl -s  printing_usage_file`, it prints the `totalbytes(printing_usage_file file is list like:aaa,240,ccc)`.

But here when I run `/perl.pl -v` or `./perl.pl -s printing_usage_file` it prints `my name`,`id` and the `totalbytes`. How can I fix it?

Comment: if i use elsif in the second if statement, /perl.pl -s printing_usage_file will print my name and ID without the totalbytes

Comment: Add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` and you will get a complaint about a bare-word 'printing_usage_file'.  It's not good practice to use bare words.  You'd also get told to declare all your variables with `my`.  Note that the scalar `$data` is unused in the rest of the script. Experienced Perl programmers use strict and warnings to make sure they haven't made any silly mistakes; novice Perl programmers should use them too, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using the `==` operator to compare two strings when you need to use the `eq` operator.

```
$ perl -e 'print q{<}, "a" == "b", q{>}, "\n";'
<1>
```

If you use the `eq` operator, it will return an empty string which is a false value.

```
$ perl -e 'print q{<}, "a" eq "b", q{>}, "\n";'
<>
```